# Add text to speech to every text node to website built with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-to-speech

The user can activate to TTS from a button then when they hover on an text, the text should be uttered.
Example is this website here https://www.monshaat.gov.sa/en 
-> You activate the text to speech from the button

[image: You activate the tts from the button]

-> Whenever you hover on an element it background color changes and the text is uttered [image: tts]

Any ideas of clean ways I can implement this to a big react project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Speech Synthesis Web API:

https://www.webcodingcenter.com/web-apis/Web-Speech-APIs

Something like this:

```
var t = document.getElementsByClassName('readOut');
for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
   t[i].addEventListener('mouseover', readout_handler);
}

function readout_handler(e){
    let text = e.target.textContent;
    //...
}
```

If you use React, you can just create a generic ReadOut element, then implement the mouseover event directly, like this:

```
function ReadOut(props){
    return <p onMouseOver={()=>readout_handler(props.children)}}>{props.children}</p>;
}
```

Then just include it in your React app everywhere:

```
<ReadOut>Hello there!</ReadOut>
```

I have not tested all the codes above, but it should not be far from the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, sorry if my question wasn't clear, I know about the Speech synthesis api. I'm asking how to implement the on hover speak functionality to every text on the page in a clean way, considering the website is very big.

Comment: @SandStone Attach a class to each of the text elements. Then implement the mouseover event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your update, While this is a cool insight this would require me to dig into the entie code and add the generic Readout handler to every text in the app
I was thinking of something that would automate this process for me

Comment: I like the idea of adding a class to each text element and then attaching an event listener but is doing plain javascript within react a good idea?

Comment: Ideally, a React developer avoids interacting directly with the DOM at a low level. However, this seems a plausible solution since you don't want to mess with the existing codebase. Also, consider using document.querySelectorAll("*")[i].nodeName to iterate through all the nodes of a specific element type. This allows you to avoid attaching the 'class' attribute altogether. If you want instant readout functionality as the pages loads, you may have to resort to MutationObserver.

Comment: It worked although it felt wrong messing with the dom directly but it got the job done nonetheless. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @SandStone In hindsight, you can do this as well: document.querySelectorAll("p, span, div") ... which should be more performant.